# Thought process at higher velocities

Tags: time, velocity

Time passes slower for objects that move at near speed of light .
Since brain activity is based on signals that also need time to travel a certain distance, does the effect cancel itself out, or would you have "more time to think" while moving at a speed of light?

Comment: What are you defining as "time to think"? Are you reacting to a particular external event? Are you just generally contemplating something internal? And "more" than what? Which two specific situations are being compared?

Comment: Also, if you're on a spaceship zooming away at some speed $v$ with respect to the Earth, time would not seem to move slower for *you* in the spaceship. (If it did, you'd be able to tell you were the one "actually" moving, which would completely go against the principle of relativity)

Comment: @probably_someone no, only internal processing; not about an external event. I wanted to compare it against processing while moving at lower velocities (of the enclosing brain/body a.k.a. me)

Comment: @Philip I wasn't thinking about the relation between two moving bodies in relation, but rather something like the "headlights at speed of light" problem. Neuronic signals would still travel in a phyical plane in all kind of directions, thus some also in the same direction as the enclosing body

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are moving at a high speed relative to someone else. The other person sees you passing by at a high speed and notes that communication between your neurons is happening more slowly.

But from your perspective, you are stationary and the *other* person is moving past you at a high speed, so you would observe that communication between *the other person*'s neurons is happening more slowly, while your own neurons are communicating at the normal speed.

Comment: As I answered Philip above, I was not thinking about two bodies in relation to eachother but rather the speeds of the body and the signals adding up. I understand that the signals move in kind of a closed system. Is that how it's "valid"?

Comment: @LuluCross The parts of your body are all moving at pretty much the same speed relative to each other. If they weren't, you'd be ripped apart pretty quickly.